# Django - ApiDetailView

Tags: django

I am following this solution on how to get specific fields from a django model:

[Select specific fields in Django get_object_or_404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565749/select-specific-fields-in-django-get-object-or-404#answer-39565956)

```
from django.core import serializers as djangoserializer  # module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'serialize'

class ProjectDetailApiView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, slug=None, format=None):
        project_instance = get_object_or_404(Project.objects.only('project_title', 'project_post'), slug=slug)
        data = djangoserializer.serialize('json', [ project_instance, ], fields=('project_title','project_post'))
        user = self.request.user
        updated = False
        viewed = False
        if not user in project_instance.project_views.all():
            viewed = True
            project_instance.project_views.add(user)
        updated = True
        data = {
            "project": data,
            "updated":updated,
            "viewed":viewed 
        }
        return Response(data)
```

Output:

```
{
    "project": "[{\"model\": \"webdata.project\", \"pk\": 4, \"fields\": {\"project_title\": \"Project 4\", \"project_post\": \"Blabla\"}}]",
    "updated": true,
    "viewed": false
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{
    "project_title": "Project 4",
    "project_post": "Blabla",
    "updated": true,
    "viewed": false
}
```

---

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serialization of regular dictionaries is very good in python.

So instead of configuring the serializer - why not just create a python dictionary with the desired data? (That's how I do it for simple things that I need only in one place.)

```
    data = {
        "project_title": project_instance.project_title,
        "project_post": project_instance.project_post,
        "updated":updated,
        "viewed":viewed 
    }
    return JSONResponse(data)
```

You haven't posted the Project model, I'm just supposing from the serializer config that the fields are named `project_title` and `project_post`.

This will return a response with status 200, mimetype application/json and the data dict as valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DRF's Serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) instead of Django's built-in serializer.

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('project_title', 'project_post', 'updated', 'viewed')


# views.py
class ProjectDetailApiView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, slug=None, format=None):
        project_instance = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=slug)
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(project_instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: `updated` and `viewed` are not model fields. You might want to add method based fields to match the code in the question.